# preg_match_all only returning first match

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I've done my homework and tested as much as possible before posting, just so it is known. As the title says my preg_match_all is not finding all matches, but if I run it the same way with phptester.net it works fine. I've read the documentation on the function, and all (as many as I could bear) of the posts here that are the same issue but nothing has worked.  In my actual code print_r is not there, I used it to prove that the 3 elements should be there. In my actual program however I can only find the first match: "-77.519506".

```
    <?php

    $coords = "<Point><coordinates>-77.519506,43.113491,0.0</coordinates></Point>";
    preg_match_all("/-?\d{1,2}\.\d{0,6}/",$coords,$latLong);

    print_r($latLong);
    print($latLong[0][0]);//prints -77.519506
    print($latLong[0][1]);//prints NULL
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://3v4l.org/OtfLl Can't reproduce it. Please provide a link to reproduce your issue or show your real code

Comment: I can reproduce it here http://www.regexr.com/ pasting his string and the regex in appropriate positions. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BTFZFHT8

Here is the full function.

Comment: SO it is known my switch statements have the indexes wrong, however with correct indexes it doesnt work

Comment: well, I don't see where you are actually defining `$addrArray[0]` so near as I can tell, the `switch` will always `default` and you are using `$latLong[1]` and `$latLong[2]` which isn't right.. or is that the index issue you fixed already?

Comment: @CrayonViolent I appreciate you attempting to help me understand. I misunderstood something about the preg_match and am a little disappointed in its limitations. I personally would prefer to add the flags on my own, but then again I am new at regex. I deleted my answer. I was not insisting anything, but instead was trying to state what I thought I understood as I went along. Obviously I was wrong and now understand a bit more. Should think about being a little less snippy in your attempts to teach however. :D Thanks either way.

Comment: Alex, I did some of my own tests based on the php requirements and I'm getting the correct results as well. I sadly have to bow out as I do not have a sufficient example to solve your issue and cannot replicate it.

Comment: Well I fixed the index issue, I meant to change that for the paste, but I forgot. $addrArray is old but default is fine, since at the moment I'm only checking to see that this preg_match_all is working.

Comment: @AlexManley soo.. is the `print_r` correctly showing all 3 values in your example?

Comment: Only when I run it from [phptester](http://www.phptester.net), if I run it from my system I get only index 0.

Comment: I suggest you update your pastebin with your corrected code. Your original question provides properly working code that gives the output you describe, which is creating more confusion than helping get you an answer.

Comment: okay, can you `echo $coords;` and post what that's actually outputting?

Comment: Since @JacobS asked, I [deliver](http://pastebin.com/9bdFwDmh). Not sure what confusion I caused, but there you go. This is correct and what is currently running on my site, it does not work though, only longitude is populated.

Comment: For debugging, add at line 18: `if(count($latLong) < 3) { echo $row . '\r\n' . print_r($latLong, true) . '\r\n' . $coords . '\r\n'; }` My belief is that there is an issue with your data.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I've echo'd to screen and got this Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => -77.518419 ) )

Comment: @JacobS What would possibly cause this behavior though? My data is in CSV format which encapsulates my $coords in another set of quotes. My thinking is if I'm able to see one of the variables I should be able to see them all, no?

Comment: @AlexManley I asked you to echo `$coords`.. is that really what's in there, or did you echo (print_r) `$latLong`? I'm looking to see what you are regexing against..

Comment: Rough suspicion? You've encountered a row that has a comma inside quote-marks which is valid, but breaks your explode.

Comment: @JacobS right.. I see he is using comma to explode so it should be impossible to have a comma in `$coords` .. yet his example posted here shows commas

Comment: @CrayonViolent I tried echoing but could not get it in CLI, I did file_put_contents("test.txt",$latLong) which gave me 

        Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => -77.518419 ) )

Comment: @AlexManley okay but I don't want to see `$latLong`, I want to see `$coords`.

Comment: @JacobS To verify yes I have a comma in my data, but I thought php would be smart enough to interpret that as a single data element?

Comment: @CrayonViolent Gotcha, Here's a single line of [data](http://pastebin.com/nV9R3LQw).

Comment: `explode` doesn't parse csv lines; it simply explodes at whatever delimiter you specify. See @JacobS answer below

Comment: @AlexManley okay so that looks like the full row *before* you `explode`, yes?  So you have that full line, then you do this to it: `list($div,$randID,$street,$city,$zipCode,$district,$coords) = explode(',',$row);` .  So I want to see what `$coords` specifically gets, e.g. `file_put_contents("test.txt",$coords);`.  Because that `list/explode` you have up there, it's *impossible* for `$coords` to have commas in it as you have shown in your OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/str_getcsv) on each line rather than explode:

```
list($div,$randID,$street,$city,$zipCode,$district,$coords) = str_getcsv($row);
```

Comment: ding ding ding we have a winner, sorry @CrayonViolent, if you know how i can hook you up with some point love!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use SimpleXML to extract the content of coordinates

```
$point = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$coords=$point->Point->coordinates;
```

and then you can simply do

```
$num=explode(',', $coordinates);
```

Comment: That was actually my initial function, I changed it to what I currently have since SimpleXML seemed to do so much more than I needed. It also would not work for me, it did something almost identical to this actually. It would only show me the first index.

Comment: Dont worry bout the plus one, whoever answers will get the credit they deserve, let me get this added to my code and see if it helps.

Comment: No go on this solution. I get uncaught exceptions that the string is not XML? odd